# Stop an object in Processing

Tags: java, processing

I'm planning to make a game using Processing. Basically I've created a character with (x, y) as his coordinates, and a 20x20 block, also with a coordinate (x1, y1). I want to keep the character from passing through the block.
I've somewhat successfully figured out how to detect collision (although the numbers aren't perfect yet):

```
if((this.wizard.getX() < this.brickwall.getX()+10 & this.wizard.getX() > this.brickwall.getX()-10) && (this.wizard.getY() < this.brickwall.getY()+10 & this.wizard.getY() > this.brickwall.getY()-10)){
            this.wizard.stop()
     }
```

With stop being the function to stop the character.
But I haven't figured out a way to make the character stop yet.
I've tried something like this

```
this.x = this.x
this.y = this.x
```

whenever the stop() method is called in the wizard class, but it doesn't work.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Without seeing the rest of the wizard class I can only make broad assumptions. The `stop()` above where you assign x the exact value is has doesn't do much if there's for example a separate update function on keypress that changes it (since stop() will simply re-assign the updated value that's already there). One idea is to store pre-collision x,y values that you use to restore positoin. (e.g. while the wizard is not colliding x, y current x,y values get copied to pre-collision x,y then are updated as the character walks. when there is a collidion, stop updating current x,y values, copy prev)

Answer (score 1):

If you want him to stop, you need the concept of speed.
This requires 2 additional member variables, velocityX and velocityY.

When the input comes, you set the velocity to 1 or -1 (or any other fitting number)

```
this.velocityX = 1
```

Movement now comes down to

```
this.x += this.velocityX
this.y += this.velocityY
```

In case you want to stop the character

```
this.velocityX = 0
this.velocityY = 0
```

In case you already moved the character INTO an object and need to get him back out, write:

```
// reverses last move
this.x -= this.velocityX
this.y -= this.velocityY

// sets speed to 0
this.velocityX = 0
this.velocityY = 0
```

But usually movement should always be done AFTER the check.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to stop the character now. However I wasn't able to get him to move again since the speed was set to 0. I have an idea, that is to detect the input in other directions, and when those inputs are recognized, the speed is set to X again, but I have the feelings that it is not the optimal option. Can you help me with it?

Comment: Just set `velocityX` and `velocityY`when you get an input.